# How to take square picture in iphone with avFoundation like in Instagram app?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimage, avfoundation, instagram

I am taking photo with AVFoundation like here:
http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

One snippet:

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
         // Do something with the attachments.
         NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
     }
     else
         NSLog(@"no attachments");

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Picture size as far as i found out is set here:

```
   AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];  
   session.sessionPreset =AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium; //medium on my iphone4 is 640*480
```

But here are only few settings possible and cant be set to custom size.

I would like taken pictures to have aspect ratio 1:1 if possible, for example 400x400 pixels (square pictures).
It seems instagram is doing it (or are they cropping images?).

How can i specify the size of taken picture to be square? I know how to change size on the phone, but if the taken picture is not square, the result is not good.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should probably be resizing your UIImage by creating a new context. Examples below

```
.....
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
UIImage *tempImage = nil;
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(400,400);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
thumbnailRect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);
thumbnailRect.size.width  = targetSize.width;
thumbnailRect.size.height = targetSize.height;

[image drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// tmpImage is resized to 400x400
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Is this the only way? I guess the image would look worse if it was resized. Is it possible to take picture of custom dimension and not resize it?

Comment: not a single camera can take pictures in different dimensions. It will always use the full resolution and size it down if you use smaller images. Instagram also have no other possibility than cropping a rect out of the full image. In this example the size is `400px` but you can see how wide the original image is and make a rect that is the same size in height. It will result in a square image and you loose some pixels above and below.

Comment: Scaling an image down will, assuming decent interpolation, make it look _better_ not worse, so your fears are unfounded.

Comment: there are different presets for photo dimensions, taking pictures with smaller size is more efficient and faster, `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I have found one code for taking a picture using AVCaptureSession, and [this is a great tutorial by "JJob"](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297). It is the best tutorial about AVCaptureSession; please read all the comments and previous tutorials of this site this will help you a lot. You can download a working sample code from [here](https://github.com/jj0b/AROverlayImageCapture).